# Codeigniter Not Loading Default Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have looked far and wide for a solution to this problem and seem to be overlooking something simple. I am using a fresh install of codeigniter on my server and added -> http://www.grocerycrud.com/codeigniter-simplicity to the application. Everything seems to be working fine except my default controller.

When I got to http://example.com/welcome I see the welcome page
When I go to http://example.com/index.php/welcome I see the welcome page

What I am trying to do is see the welcome page from above right when I visit 
http://example.com

COMMON SETTINGS

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myapp/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Ensure that welcome controller starts with Uppercase letter so controller class name will be "Welcome". another thing you have to ensure that index() action is exists

Comment: what are you seeing when you try to go to http://example.com?

Comment: class Welcome extends CI_Controller

Comment: Yeah, I have the controller named right and when I go to example I see the example page. I would guess its something to do with the default_controller since it tells it to use the welcome controller by default. Inside my welcome controller I am using public function index() but still nothing.

Comment: I will start over with a fresh install and see what I get again.